# How can I make iOS mail display the sender of an AOL-originated Google Groups message?

Tags: gmail, mobile-mail

As recently mentioned [on this webapps question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62737/why-does-google-change-my-from-header-to-have-via-me-in-it), Google Groups has started re-writing the `From:` address information on messages originating with Yahoo & AOL users.

For Google Groups mailing lists that are set to "replies go to the group", the AOL/Yahoo message originator's email address is placed in an `X-Original-Sender:` header while the textual portion of the email address (if any) is placed in the textual portion of the `From:` header along with a "via  *mailing-list-name*" (e.g., "From: myaolscreename via Mailing List Name  <mailing-list-address@googlegroups.com>"). This is apparently done so that Google doesn't appear to the recipients' email servers as having tried to spoof email from AOL or Yahoo.

In iOS Mail, this header rewrite makes it difficult to determine who really did originate the mail-- since there is (typically) already a contact for the mailing list address on the device, the contact information (e.g., "Mailing List Name") is displayed by iOS Mail as the `From:` of the AOL/Yahoo-originated Google Groups message (obscuring the "myaolscreename via" information).

The easiest workaround appears to be to start to forward the message and scroll down to look at the textual portion of the included original message-- in that case, the "From: myaolscreename via Mailing List Name..." becomes visible.  However, even this is problematic because the screen name might not actually be meaningful (or present); plus there's the need to explain how/why to do this to non-technical google group members.

Another workaround seems to be to require all the Google Group members to use a Google account (and insist that they select a "real name" that is meaningful); the resistance to assimilation makes the first part difficult (and enforcing the second part seems like a full-time job).

Is there any other setting/shortcut/feature/technique that can be used/enabled to unmask the AOL/Yahoo author information?

Comment: More importantly, How can we get the rest of the internet mail providers to follow [yahoo's move](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFcQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcworld.com%2Farticle%2F2141120%2Fyahoo-email-antispoofing-policy-breaks-mailing-lists.html&ei=zDcTVJauK8KtyASUsoCwDQ&usg=AFQjCNET640yzVwHY7fVyNF3uQxNEWEVRg&sig2=0t2s-Xd1wqMfQlrChYUlqg)? Doing so will make impossible many of the techniques spammers use to make spam for us...  Personally I prefer my email addresses being unspoof-able anyway.

Comment: The same happens with Mails from various Airlines like air-lingus, especially when they are sent to a GMail address. Apple should use at least the X-Original-Sender to show the actual sender if no FROM: is present. Instead, Apple shows the own Name, which is basically an ugly bug in my eyes